# Java generics - erasure concept

Tags: java, generics, types, erasure

I have some code as follows:

```
public class java_generic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        T t = new X();
        t.<Object>m(new Object());
        t.<String>m(new String());

    }

    static class T {
        <E> void m (E e){
            System.out.println("here is T");
        }
    }

    static class X extends T {
        void m (String o){
            System.out.println("here is X");            
        }
    }

}
```

From my understanding, after type erasure, class `T` will become this:

```
    static class T {
        void m (Object e){
            System.out.println("here is T");
        }
    }
```

and m is overloaded.

As having `m(Object)` and `m(String)`, I expect the result would be

```
here is T
here is X
```

However, the result is

```
here is T
here is T
```

I wonder why the result would be this.

Comment: Please don't name your actual class `T`. One-letter names are usually reserved for generic type names like `<T>` `<E>` `<K>` `<V>` `<U>`.

Comment: Also, you should not use such a code in production

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question. You just need to fully follow the consequences. Do the erasure for **all** your code and you get this:

```
public class java_generic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T t = new X();
        t.m(new Object());
        t.m(new String());
    }

    static class T {
        void m (Object e){
            System.out.println("here is T");
        }
    }

    static class X extends T {
        void m (String o){
            System.out.println("here is X");            
        }
    }
}
```

That hopefully makes it obvious that `X.m` simply does not override `T.m` and thus a call through a `T` reference can never invoke `X.m`.

Answer (score 2):

Since **T** is a superclass of **X**, and instance of **X** is assigned to superclass Object **t**, you can't really access subclass **X** methods. Thus both

```
   t.<Object>m(new Object());
   t.<String>m(new String());
```

invoking the superclass generic method.

Now check this way -

```
public class java_generic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        X x = new X();
        x.<Object>m(new Object());
        x.<String>m(new String());

    }

    static class T {
        <E> void m (E e){
            System.out.println("here is T");
        }
    }

    static class X extends T {
        void m (String o){
            System.out.println("here is X");            
        }
    }

}
```